# Write a pickle file in to Minio Object Storage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, minio

Currently, I use the below approach to save a pickle file:

```
with open('model/tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
   pickle.dump(t, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

This is storing the file into my local directory, and later I am uploading from my local to Minio using:

```
minioClient = Minio(endpoint = endpoint, access_key = minio_access_key, secret_key = minio_secret_key)
minioClient.fput_object(bucket_name='model', object_name='tokenizer.pickle', file_path='model/tokenizer.pickle')
```

How can I directly save the file into Minio, without writing in local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can first use 
`bytes_file = pickle.dumps(t)` to convert your object to bytes, and then use `io.BytesIO(bytes_file)` this way:

```
client.put_object(
            bucket_name=bucket_name,
            object_name=object_name,
            data=io.BytesIO(bytes_file),
            length=len(bytes_file)
        )
```

Then just do

```
pickle.loads(client.get_object(bucket_name=bucket_name,
                               object_name=path_file).read())
```

Comment: I've updated your answer. Not sure if its because boto3 has updated some of its libraries but the code below should work now.

Answer (score 2):

The top answer has the right idea but is incorrect. It doesn't even run as the arguments in the `put_object` method isn't valid. Also since the OP wants to write the file into Minio (which is hosted on premise), you must specify the `endpoint_url`.

Here is some sample code from start to finish that should work. Replace the `endpoint_url` with whatever public ip your ec2 is hosted on. I used `localhost` as a simple example.

```
import boto3
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle


ACCESS_KEY = 'BLARG'
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'KWARG'

#sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4))
                                     , columns=list('ABCD'))
bytes_file = pickle.dumps(df)

bucket_name = 'mlflow-minio'
object_name = 'df.pkl'

s3client = boto3.client('s3'
                        ,endpoint_url = 'http://localhost:9000/'
                        ,aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY
                        ,aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                       )

#places file in the Minio bucket
s3client.put_object(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=object_name,
            Body=io.BytesIO(bytes_file)
        )

#Now to load the pickled file
response = s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_name)

body = response['Body'].read()
data = pickle.loads(body)

#sample records
print (data.head())
```

Comment: s3client.put_object(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=object_name,
            Body=io.BytesIO(bytes_file)
        )     There is error in the name of argument you are passsing. For eg bucket should be replaced with bucket_name. Have a look at @hglr answer for reference.